Apply custom border to each row in a List with SwiftUI
So, I want a List in SwiftUI, where the border of each row depends on some function of the contents of the row. Normally I can do this easily with .border() but List seems to take care of the styling for the elements itself, adding padding and that.
The closest I have is below, which is quite far from what I'm after. This produces the borders around the text fields, but I want instead to produce borders around the whole cell.
struct ListDemoView: View {
    @State private var nums: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    var body: some View {
        List (nums, id: \.self) { num in
            Section {
                Text("Num: \(num)")
            }
            .border(num % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.blue)
        }

    }
}



Thanks for all the great answers everyone, I don't have the reputation required to upvote somehow, but it was great to see how many different ways there are to accomplish this! I guess SwiftUI is more flexible than I thought!

A simple way to add a border is to stroke the border of the .listRowBackground. This way, the row insets can be left at the default.

When the list style is .insetGrouped (the default), the List applies its own rounded rectangle as clip shape to the section. The corner radius for this clip shape appears to be about 10.

To avoid thinning at the corners, the rounded rectangle for the rows needs to use a corner radius at least as large as the clip shape for the section, in other words >= 10.

If the border is stroked using .stroke then the clip shape also clips half the width of the border. Use .strokeBorder to keep the stroke inside the border of the shape.


Btw, the issue of the clip shape affects all the answers to this post.
List (nums, id: \.self) { num in
    Section {
        Text("Num: \(num)")
    }
    .listRowBackground(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(.background)
            .strokeBorder(num % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
    )
}



This approach will add a border around each row of the list. Currently, each row of the list is wrapped in its own Section, so the gaps between rows are actually gaps between sections. You can achieve the same look by removing the Section and adding .listRowSpacing to the List:
List (nums, id: \.self) { num in
    Text("Num: \(num)")
        .listRowBackground(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(.background)
                .strokeBorder(num % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
        )
}
.listRowSpacing(35)


To borders around the entire row in a SwiftUI List, you’ll need to wrap each row in a container like ZStack or RoundedRectangle to control the border explicitly.
struct ListDemoView: View {
    @State private var nums: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    var body: some View {
        List (nums, id: \.self) { num in
            Section {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .stroke(num % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                    Text("Num: \(num)")
                }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 1, leading: 1, bottom: 1, trailing: 1))
            }
        }
    }
}



List has default insets/padding and background. You can try to cover it up or you can remove it and add your own, depending on what you're trying to achieve.
See the comments in the code below:
import SwiftUI

struct ListRowBorder: View {
    @State private var nums: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    private let borderWidth: CGFloat = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        List (nums, id: \.self) { num in
            Section {
                HStack {
                    Text("Num: \(num)")
                }
                
                //Clear the default row padding
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: borderWidth, leading: borderWidth, bottom: borderWidth, trailing: borderWidth))
                
                //Clear the default row background
                .listRowBackground(
                    Color.clear
                )
                
                //Add padding
                .padding(15)
                
                //Full width
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                //Add background
                .background {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    
                        //Background color
                        .fill(.white)
                    
                        //Add border
                        .stroke(num % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.blue, lineWidth: borderWidth)
                }
            }
        }
        .listSectionSpacing(10)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListRowBorder()
}
                        




Try this simple approach using a .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading)
to ensure the Text takes the full row space.
struct ListDemoView1: View {
    @State private var nums: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    var body: some View {
        List (nums, id: \.self) { num in
            Section {
                Text("Num: \(num)")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading) // <-- here
            }
            .border(num % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.blue)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
    }
}

Or
struct ListDemoView2: View {
    @State private var nums: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    var body: some View {
        List (nums, id: \.self) { num in
            Section {
                Text("Num: \(num)")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading) // <-- here
            }
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(num % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
            )
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 2, bottom: 2, trailing: 2))
        }
    }
}

